# Jump to next merge conflict in project using Magit and Smerge

Tags: magit, smerge

When I am resolving merge conflicts with Magit and Smerge, is there a way for me to cycle through all merge conflicts in the project? Currently I can only move through them one file at a time.

I wrote something like this as as utility but it's not great:

```
(defun jump-to-first-merge-conflict ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-status)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (magit-section-forward-sibling)
  (magit-section-forward-sibling)
  (magit-section-forward)
  (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "<return>")))
```

It would be nice if I could just use `smerge` in a project context, instead of a file context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just 7 hours ago to Smerge was added [a new command to do exactly that](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/vc/smerge-mode.el?id=2ede38ce4bf336c573450c61a2e9a41fb7ebe1be#n1439). Now you can use <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>smerge-vc-next-conflict</kbd> to either jump to the next conflict in focused buffer or to the next conflicted file in the repository that the file belongs to.

Don't forget to use `(require 'smerge-mode)` for this function to appear.

---

For those who can't for some reason upgrade Emacs, I can share an analogous function `next-conflict` I've been using:

```lisp
(require 'vc)

(defun smerge-next-safe ()
  "Return t on success, nil otherwise"
  (ignore-errors (not (smerge-next))))

(defun next-conflict ()
  (interactive)
  (when (not (smerge-next-safe))
    (vc-find-conflicted-file)
    ;; At this point, the caret will only be at a conflict marker if the file did not
    ;; correspond to an opened buffer. Otherwise, we need to jump to a marker explicitly.
    (unless (looking-at "^<<<<<<<")
      (let ((prev-pos (point)))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (unless (smerge-next-safe)
          (goto-char prev-pos)
          (message "No conflicts found"))))))
```

Comment: thank you, that's all I needed!

Comment: I am having `Symbol’s function definition is void: vc-find-conflicted-file` error

Comment: @alper try evaluating `(require 'vc)` to see if that helps. But worth noting that this is odd, because for me it's available even if I run `emacs -Q` to not load any configs. What Emacs version you have?

Comment: I am using `Emacs 26.3`, seems like `(require 'vc)` fixed the issue

Comment: This does not work if I am end of the file and there is a conflict in the same buffer/file. Is there any way to fix that too? Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63413/finding-git-conflict-in-the-same-buffer-if-cursor-is-end-of-the-buffer

Comment: Good idea, done

Comment: Would this jump to any conflict on another file ? This was working that way but now it won't jump to any conflict  lets say in B.txt file if I am in A.txt file

Comment: @alper could you please write how to reproduce? Can't reproduce it here. What I did: I just copied the whole code here, and evaluated it through `eval-region`. Then I created a conflict by cherry-picking an arbitrary commit from the past on a project. Then, I was at a file `smb.py`: I executed M-x `next-conflict`, and it switched me to another file with a conflict. I repeated it both with the other file pre-opened and not, and I always get correctly switched to the conflicted file, and I always end up on the line with conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Magit does not support that currently, but I have just added a note to a [related feature request](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3164).

Comment: Is this feature still considered to be added into `magit`? Jumping next conflict in the project