# finding git conflict in the same buffer if cursor is at end of the buffer

Tags: magit, smerge

I am using `next-conflict` to detect is there any git conflict, using following answer:
[Jump to next merge conflict in project using Magit and Smerge](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47895/18414). I experience that if I am at the end of the file/buffer and if there is a conflict in the same buffer/file, the conflict is not found. But if I switch into another buffer, or go to top of the buffer it iss found.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

---

setup:

```
(defun smerge-try-smerge ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "^<<<<<<< " nil t)
      (require 'smerge-mode)
      (smerge-mode 1))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)

(defun smerge-next-safe ()
    "returns t on success, nil otherwise"
  (condition-case err
      (not (smerge-next))
    ('error
     nil)))

(require 'vc)
(defun next-conflict ()  ;; key-binding
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
    (when (not (smerge-next-safe))
      (vc-find-conflicted-file)
      (if (eq buffer (current-buffer))
          (message "No conflicts found")
        (goto-char 0)
        (smerge-next-safe)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea. Here's a `next-conflict` function that wraps around whenever there is no more conflicted files, but the current one still has conflicts:

```lisp
(defun next-conflict ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
    (when (not (smerge-next-safe))
      (vc-find-conflicted-file)
      (when (eq buffer (current-buffer))
        (let ((prev-pos (point)))
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (unless (smerge-next-safe)
            (goto-char prev-pos)
            (message "No conflicts found")))))))
```

I modified the answer you are referring to as well *(it was mine answer)* as such behavior is more intuitive. [And changed behavior accordingly of](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=5b10ca8f4f70cbdc51970b8b756d11f1dbf6e2f6) the built-in emacs function with similar functional.

Might be worth noting that I looked at how `smerge-next` is defined, and it is defined with `easy-mmode-define-navigation` macro. As far as I look through the macro there's no way to make `smerge-next` wrap around the search *(e.g. by changing some variable or something like that)*, so I open-coded the wrapping higher the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Should I update the changes from this questions or from original answer?

Comment: @alper from the original answer, there was an additional fix that I hesitate to include here, since this question is specific to "how to modify the code from question to resolve the question".

Comment: I am not sure why but this won't detect conflicts on different files if exist

Comment: @alper me neither  I am not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry for keep bringing this up , I have tried: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b60883e1bebb9a9a3d3a5520aaded98d which does not detect any conflict if I am at the end of file, does it work on your end?

Comment: @alper np. So, yeah, I can't seem to reproduce what you describe. I [recorded a screencast here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlwv0ImKK-g), hopefully I do there what you expect me to do? In particular, I go to the end of file, and then I execute `next-conflict`. It always brings me back to the conflict marker.

Comment: @alper so, what I'd try to do in your case: try inserting `(print "here")`s on various lines after the `(when (eq buffer (current-buffer))…` condition. If you don't see the caret going to the conflict marker specifically when you're at the end of the file, that means something goes wrong after that condition. The `(smerge-next-safe)` function per se is not able to wrap around, so what the code does is it saves your current position, then goes to the buffer beginning and executes `(smerge-next-safe)` from there. Then if it returned `nil`, it goes back to original position and prints a message.

Comment: @alper another thought: by any chance, doesn't evaluating a `(require 'smerge-mode)` line before executing `(next-conflict)` help?

Comment: Hm I did not had `(require 'smerge-mode)` but `(eval-after-load 'smerge-mode
  (lambda ()
    (define-key smerge-mode-map (kbd "C-c v") smerge-basic-map)
    (define-key smerge-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") smerge-basic-map)))
` before `(next-conflict)` // but didn't help. Can you share me a minimal code that works that I can try to integrate into my init.el file

Comment: @alper as you can see in the screencast the code that works for me is the one you provided a link to. I don't think I have anything else to share. You'd need to try to pin down what part of code exactly doesn't work for you, I'm afraid there's not much else I can do because I simply can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah my bad :( I was using `C-c-v n` for next conflict instead when I use binding for next-conflict in your code it worked! When I am on top of `<<<<<<< HEAD` and if there is no more conflict it jumps right away to end of file

Comment: @alper no worries! I didn't really understand what was the problem but I'm glad that it solved. Regarding you last comment about the caret jumping to the end of the file when it is right at the beginning of a `<<<<<<< HEAD`, in absence of other conflicts: it is a bug in `(smerge-next)` function. It is reproducible it by evaluating this function alone while at the beginning of the last conflict marker. At some point I dug into the Emacs code to fix it, I figured the `smerge-mode` is defined through `easy-mmode` framework, and the problem lies somewhere inside it. I didn't dig further into it.

Comment: Should I ask it as an another question, if it could be helpful? Ah I messed up the keybindings so I wasn't using your function , and it was using the default one

Comment: @alper as you wish, but in case you count on me to solve this bug: I don't find myself motivated, actually. For me it's just a rare corner-case, so… 