# How to disable `flycheck` while merging Git conflicts

Tags: flycheck, colors, smerge

I am using following solution for [merge Git conflicts in Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47895/18414), which is based on `smerge`. During merging `smerge-mode` creates  `<<<<<<< HEAD` , `||||||||| parent` lines for conflict detection.

But flycheck catches them as `flycheck-error` and changes their colors, hence they may become unreadable.

Would it be possible to prevent `flycheck-mode` to be disabled during merging or just can it ignore specific patterns to detected as `flycheck-error' like:` <<<<<<< HEAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `M-x flycheck-mode` to turn off flycheck in current buffer. Or alternatively, you can disable it for specific hooks (in this case `smerge-mode`):

```lisp
(add-hook 'smerge-mode-hook (lambda () (flycheck-mode -1)))
```

**Note: I haven't tested this code yet. So, I don't know if this works or not.*

Comment: I have tested and it works.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am getting `Error running timer ‘lsp--on-idle’: (user-error "Flycheck mode disabled")` error. After its disabled, it does not re-enable itself. Is it possible when `smerge-mode` is close automatically to re-enabe itself?